# find ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, kinect, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my system is ubuntu11.10,installed with ROS( electric) and openni_kinect.

I want to use the mit kinect demo,then I fellow the guide from http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Customizable%20Buttons

1.I first perform the General Installation.

2.environment is setup, run:

"rosmake impromptu_buttons"

then, terminal display that:

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['impromptu_buttons']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/jung/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120604-205316
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['impromptu_buttons'] to: []
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['impromptu_buttons']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

It seems rosmake is unable to find the package.
I should add the path to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
How I add the path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35662/find--ros_package_path/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-06-04**:
This is identical to your previous question - you should close one or the other. Also, you might want to indicate what you've tried to do on your own to figure this out. Did you read the documentation I linked to in your previous question? What didn't make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you were following [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) tutorial, just put all ros packages in the directory ~/ros_workspace.

However, I recommend using [rosws](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html). It provides a more structured way to manage local checkouts of ROS repositories and the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1